# Does recreating a file reuse the previous inode?

Tags: linux

I  have a file `a.txt`.

If I delete the file and create an empty file with `a.txt` at the same location, will that influence the inode details of old file? or will a new inode will get created?

Comment: What is the programming angle to make this question [on-topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) here?

Comment: you can test by yourself, can't you? `ls -i a.txt`

Comment: @Psytho - trial and error is great, until it gives you an answer that only applies in certain circumstances...

Comment: @Attie The same applies to your answer. Which is nothing else than try and error.

Comment: Right, but my answer is "_it depends_" (with proof), while your "_give it a go_" approach might lead them to use one or the other result, which depending on their local filesystem could be incorrect for the end user.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It depends on your filesystem...

On ext4 I see the following: (inode reuse)

```
$ touch a.txt
$ stat -c%i a.txt
1316644

$ rm a.txt

$ touch a.txt
$ stat -c%i a.txt
1316644
```

On ZFS I see the following: (new inode assigned)

```
$ touch a.txt
$ stat -c%i a.txt
15585

$ rm a.txt

$ touch a.txt
$ stat -c%i a.txt
15586
```

---

`stat -c%i ${FILENAME}` will show the inode for the given file.

Note that inodes are not typically created/destroyed, but rather exist in perpetuity and are used to either record file information or are marked as "*unused*".

---

Note also, that on an active system you cannot place any guarantee on the same inode being reused, as it may be used by another file between your deletion and creation. i.e: the delete/create operation is not [atomic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linearizability).

On ext4:

```
$ touch a.txt
$ stat -c%i a.txt
1316644

$ rm a.txt

$ touch b.txt
$ stat -c%i b.txt
1316644

$ touch a.txt
$ stat -c%i a.txt
1316645
```

Comment: Try the following on ext4: delete a file, create another with a different name, create one more file with the original name. Or wait a while between removing and creating.

Comment: I don't think that's any different... delete `a.txt` inode `1316644` is free'd, inode `1316644` is used by new `b.txt`, inode `1316645` is used by new `a.txt`

Comment: I added a bit to explain that.

Answer (score 3):

It may depend of tons of things (file system, other actions currently executed on the same filesystems, previous operations on the file system, etc.).

Common Linux file systems are implemented through an inode table and file clusters. The inode contains the file meta data (commonly creation/modification/access times, owner/group ids and permissions) and the address of the allocation table of the file (a cluster that contains the addresses of all data clusters). The inode table has a fixed size that is normally given at formatting time.

A name of a file is only an entry in a folder, and a folder is only a special file that contains mapping from names to inodes.

When you delete a file, all of its data clusters and allocation tables are returned to the free cluster pool for later reuse, and the inode is marked as free.

When you later create a brand new file, just re-using a previous name, the file system looks for a free inode and uses it. Whether it uses the oldest free one, the newest free one, or the next one in a round robbin way is up to the file system implementation. And the result of any of those algorithms will vary if other creations/destructions as occured since the initial creation of the file...

TL/DR: The short (an only reliable) answer is: *it depends*