# File is deleted and recreated while reading. How to handle it?

Tags: c++, c, file, posix

I have a program (let's call it the consumer) that opens and keeps reading a file. The file is created and written by another program (let's call it the producer). Some times, the file gets deleted (manually) and recreated by the producer. The problem is, the consumer doesn't know that and keeps reading the old file through the old FD, which does't have the new data. My question is, do we have a way to detect this situation in consumer (without adding some kind of communication mechanism between the consumer and the producer).

My preliminary idea is, when I open the file, I use `fstat()` to get the inode's number of the file. And I can use `stat()` later to get the inode's number again. If the inode's number is the same, then it is the same file, if the number changes, it means the file has been deleted and created already. So I can reopen the file and data can be read from the new file.

Does this idea always work? Is there any other better ways to do that. Thank you.

Comment: I just noticed, that inode's number could be reused: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51019714/does-recreating-a-file-reuse-the-previous-inode.
So, maybe just checking the inode's number isn't a good idea.

Comment: I found another information that might be useful: st_nlink (Number of hard links). It will become 0 if the file gets deleted.

Answer (score 1):

> do we have a way to detect this situation in consumer

On linux you can watch with `inotify` the directory of the file and wait for events like `moved_to` or `delete` on that file and do an action then.

In pseudocode in shell it would look like:

```
watched_file=....
dir_of_watched_file=$(dirname "$watched_file")
inotifywait -m -q -e moved_to --no-newline --format "%w%f%0" "$dir_of_watched_file" |
while IFS= read -r -d '' line; do
     if [[ "$line" = "$watched_file" ]]; then
            : och, the file was moved to
            reopen "$watched_file"
     fi
done
```

Comment: Thanks, but it seems I need to install a toolset to get this feature. For this problem, I kind of need a more portable solution. Because the target platform is FreeBSD.

Comment: `Because the target platform is FreeBSD.` Then you should not tag your question with `linux`.... . And no, inotifywait is a linux shell command that you need to install - the inotify api is exposed by the __linux__ kernel and is part of glibc - should be available on any __linux__.

Comment: Ok, I will change it.

Comment: For a more portable way use `libinotify` which has a [BSD port](https://github.com/libinotify-kqueue/libinotify-kqueue).

Comment: ^^ on freebsd they have kqueue. But I would rather go with an OS-independent library like libevent that already handles multiple platforms by itself.

Comment: Can `kqueue` detect this situation?

Comment: I do not know - I never worked in freebsd.